# Updating multiple data when changing ListBox selection in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, listbox

I'm new to databases and Windows Forms, and wasn't able to find the solution to this. I have a Windows Form Application with a ListBox. The ListBox contains all the entries in the current database. When I select an entry, I want to display all the columns of that selection. For example, if I have a Table of "people" entries, and each entry has data for columns age, weight, height, etc, I would like to change labels on the form to correspond to the selection's statistics.

(I've seen this done by Data Binding, but this can only works with one Display Member.)

essentially:

```
private void currentItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // something like:
    // label1.Text = selectedId.ColumnValue1;
    // label2.Text = selectedId.ColumnValue2;
    // ...
}
```

As a sub-question, I will only be dealing with one small database for this application. Is there a way to only have to call the Select statement once, put all the data into a DataTable, then just draw from that? I imagine constantly calling from the database would be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Feel the power of data binding!

Place this code to the form constructor.

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();

    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    // Assume that DataTable is populated from database.
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

    dataTable.Rows.Add("John", 42);
    dataTable.Rows.Add("Smit", 33);


    var dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

    var listBoxNames = new ListBox { Parent = this, Top = dataGridView.Bottom + 10 };
    listBoxNames.DataSource = dataTable;
    listBoxNames.DisplayMember = "Name";

    var labelName = new Label { Parent = this, Top = listBoxNames.Top, Left = listBoxNames.Right + 20 };
    labelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable, "Name");

    var textBoxName = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = labelName.Bottom + 10, Left = labelName.Left };
    textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable, "Name");

    var numericAge = new NumericUpDown { Parent = this, Top = textBoxName.Bottom + 10, Left = textBoxName.Left };
    numericAge.DataBindings.Add("Value", dataTable, "Age");
}
```

Now you can select the data in the DataGridView as well as in the ListBox.

You can also edit the data in the DataGridView and TextBox and NumericUpDown.